# Getting error while compiling c++ files using GCC on heroku

Tags: node.js, gcc, heroku

I am making online CPP compiler.It works good on my machine but when i deployed it on heroku i am getting an error from GCC. 
 "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory"

i am using node js child process to compile the file

`` var proc = spawn('gcc', [`program` + ".cpp", "-o", `program`, '-lstdc++']); ``

where program.cpp is the source file.

I got the error `"gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory"`
can you please tell how it can be resolved.

Comment: As i have mentioned that i making an online c compiler like cppshell [link](http://cpp.sh/ ) that will provide  an online platform for compiling your c code. so every user have its own c code and we have to compile it on runtime for the output of the code. @Chris

Comment: This works on your local machine because you have installed both
the `gcc` and `g++` frontends of GCC. With `g++` you get the C++ compiler, `cc1plus`
which enables you to compile C++ source files using `gcc`. They would normally
be compiled used `g++`. But on your Heroku cloud host,
`g++` is not installed so `gcc` fails to invoke `cc1plus` when presented with
a C++ source file.

Comment: so can you please guide me how can i install  ```gcc``` and  ```g++``` frontends of GCC on heroku dyno @MikeKinghan

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that or I'd have written an answer. I don't use heroku but the failure is reproducible on any system if you try to use `gcc` to invoke the compiler for a language - C++, go, d, fortran, ada - that is not installed. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50616083/1362568) might help you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @Wajid?

Comment: I ended up using Docker. It actually worked pretty well for me. @WilliamHampshire